# Making opengl work (paint)faster

Tags: opengl, vbo

im trying to paint 512*512 points , which each point uses its neighbors.
for example

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
glVertex(x,y,z);
glVertex(x+1,y,z);
glVertex(x,y,z+1);
glVertex(x+1,y,z+1);
glEnd();
```

the problem is that it works quite slow , i know i can use VBO (working with CUDA aswell) but im not sure how to define the VBO to work with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP and how to set the painting order of the vertices.

Comment: If your triangle is covering only one pixel, why don't avoid sending vertices data and generate pixels using a single quad and a fragment shader?

Comment: @LucaPiccioni: Why do you think the triangle would cover only one pixel? You don't know the used projection and modelview matrix.

Comment: @datewolf Really sorry for the bad sentence, the intent was to ask about model/projection matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to use VBOs (there are variants, using the old Vertex Array API, directly uploading the data with glBufferData and other nice things).

```
GLuint vbo; // this variable becomes a handles, keep them safe
GLuint idx;

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*512*512*3, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GLfloat *vbuf = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE);
fill_with_vertex_data(vbo);
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

glGenBuffers(1, &idx);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint)*512*512*4, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GLfloat *ibuf = glMapBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE);
GLuint restart_index = 0xffff;
fill_with_indices_restart(ibuf, restart_index); // 0xffff is the restart index to be used, delimiting each triangle strip.
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);

/* ... */

glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertex_position_location);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glVertexAttrxPointer(vertex_position_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, idx);
glPrimitiveRestartIndex(restart_index);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, count, 0);
```

Comment: exactlly what i was looking for. i have only one question . as i mentioned earlier , i need to paint the GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP in a specific order , where do i set it?
i guess it has something to do with "vertex_position_location" , but how do i set it? 
again , thanks for the example!

Comment: @igalk: No the vertex_position_location is the vertex attribute location of the shader to be used (you are using shaders, are you? If not, you should). The order of the vertices drawn is specified in that index array fill_with_indices_restart(ibuf). BTW: The way you're using triangle strips doesn't make much sense. Just draw two triangles, if you want to form a quad. Triangle strips are useful for at least 20 vertices in a single strip.

Comment: thanks for the comment!
i've to add few things , well im actually using TRIANGLE_STRIP for 4 vertices, the reason for using it, is because i've heard it's much faster than using regular GL_TRIANGLES for height map painting.
now, about the shaders, i've not used them ever before , the data exists as a big float array, will it affect me incase i do decide to apply the shadres method?
and last thing , VBO with bmp textures is possible? 
many thanks for your help!

Comment: @igalk: It's only faster for heigt map painting if you actually draw strips. Drawing only 4 vertices, and restarting the primitive then, will perform worse than plain triangles. Yes, triangle strips are the way do go for terrain renderers, but not this way. Texturing is completely independent of VBOs. You load a texture image, you provide texture coordinates (and for heightmap you can use a vertex shader to genererate them).

Comment: i guess i will have to think about it then , i will read about VBOs and how to apply textures on them.
thanks again

Comment: @igalk: You don't apply textures to VBOs. You apply them to drawn geometry, which may originate from everywhere. It's just glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_...) or binding a shader accessing a sampler and *BOOM* texturing. Again, this noting special on the vertex side. Only an additional attribute, but in the case of heightmap the XY coordinates do as texture coordinates just fine, so no extra attribute needed in your case.

Comment: something's still not quite clear , i know that when using VBOs i have to copy my points array to an external buffer which is located somewhere on the GPU, it's my responsibility to provide vectors which describe the painting order and so on ,the painting itself is executed by gldrawelements for example, but where do i specify the texture drawing? as you said earlier , the texture is applied on a given geometric shape by glvertex().

Comment: @igalk: bind the texture and provide texture coordinates as yet another vertex attribute array.