# OpenGL VBO painting order

Tags: opengl, vbo

I'm planning on using VBO in order to display a large points array, around 512x512. In order to display it each vertex depends on its nearest neighbors. For example if I have the following table:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7
  8, 9,10,11,12,13,
 14,15,16,17,18,19]
```

and I would like to draw a polygon using 5th point I will have to use the following code:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)
glVertex(Points5)
glVertex(Points6)
glVertex(Points11)
glVertex(Points12)
glEnd()
```

and so on for any other point..

I know that at any given moment my buffer holds only 512x512 points, but how can I "teach" it to draw in that specific way using the GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP and VBOs?

Comment: Was there something about the discussion you had in the comments of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8293488/734069) that confused you? Datenwolf already told you not to do this "draw each as a separate strip" thing. That's probably why your performance was terrible with immediate mode.

Comment: Nicol Bolas: well i couldn;t find the part where in the given code(your link) i specify the way of painting as shown in the above glVertex example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **don't draw a separate triangle strip for each individual quad**! Just split each of these quads into two triangles and put all the vertex indices of these triangles into a single index array/buffer, like Brett Hale suggests. This way you can then draw the whole mesh with a single call to `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ...)`.

If you don't know wth an index array is or what a vertex array/buffer is in general, then you should delve a little deeper into this topic. But by all means, please stay away from your current solution of drawing a single strip for each quad. It may sound great at first (regarding number of vertices to send) but it isn't. Remember that the advantage of VBOs is not just the possible GPU storage, but also the fact that you don't need a driver call for each individual primitive and your current solution can only be done that way.

You could also use `GL_QUADS` instead of `GL_TRIANGLES`. This way you still only need 4 indices per quad (in contrast to 6 when using triangles) and can still draw it in one single call. But also keep in mind that `GL_QUADS` has been dropped from the core profile of newer OpenGL versions (3+) and also from ES. So `GL_TRIANGLES` might be a more portable solution (and the GPU splits it into triangles anyway).

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution is to express the primitives in terms of indices, using an index (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER) buffer. [ref](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_Data).

**Edit:**

I can't tell from your question, but you might want to investigate degenerate triangle strips (adding degenerate triangles) to avoid excessive draw calls.

Comment: Though degenrate triangle strip might be something to look into, but definitely not for each individual quad, like he wants to do it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, another question is that during run time,
i first calculate each point seperatly(CUDA),and then, during the painting(glVertex) process i have to reconsturct my entire data array structure so it will hold the a quadric painting style (add every time 3 additional points to the current point - see my question from the painting style)?
wont it get slower? because i first have to rearrange to points and then paint them.